# TFS 2015 pass variable to Wix at build

Tags: visual-studio-2015, wix, tfs-2015, azure-pipelines

I'm working on creating build definition on TFS 2015. We have `*.sln` file and referenced `*.wixproj`there. In Wix proj we are using variables as follows:
`<File Id="MyFile" Name="MyFile.dll" Source="$(var.SourceLocation)" Vital="yes"/>`

This variable `$(var.SourceLocation)` is passed to `candle.exe`:

> C:\Program Files (x86)\WiX Toolset v3.10\bin\candle.exe -d"SourceLocation=D:\agent_work\2\SomeLocation\bin\Debug\"

It work locally because we have such code there:

```
    <Project ToolsVersion="4.0" DefaultTargets="Build" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <Configuration Condition=" '$(Configuration)' == '' ">Debug</Configuration>
    <Platform Condition=" '$(Platform)' == '' ">x86</Platform>
    <ProductVersion>3.8</ProductVersion>
    <ProjectGuid>{63f50ecb-3c8f-448c-ad0d-43739e6ad5f1}</ProjectGuid>
    <SchemaVersion>2.0</SchemaVersion>
    <OutputName>Setup AddIn</OutputName>
    <OutputType>Package</OutputType>
    <WixTargetsPath Condition=" '$(WixTargetsPath)' == '' AND '$(MSBuildExtensionsPath32)' != '' ">$(MSBuildExtensionsPath32)\Microsoft\WiX\v3.x\Wix.targets</WixTargetsPath>
    <WixTargetsPath Condition=" '$(WixTargetsPath)' == '' ">$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\Microsoft\WiX\v3.x\Wix.targets</WixTargetsPath>
    <SccProjectName>SAK</SccProjectName>
    <SccProvider>SAK</SccProvider>
    <SccAuxPath>SAK</SccAuxPath>
    <SccLocalPath>SAK</SccLocalPath>
    <SourceLocation Condition="$(SourceLocation) == '' ">$(SolutionDir)SomeLocation\bin\$(Configuration)\</SourceLocationAddIn>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Debug|x86' ">
    <OutputPath>$(SolutionDir)OutPutpathLocation\bin\$(Configuration)\</OutputPath>
    <IntermediateOutputPath>obj\$(Configuration)\</IntermediateOutputPath>
    <DefineConstants>SourceLocation=$(SourceLocation)</DefineConstants>
    <SuppressIces>ICE30;ICE91</SuppressIces>
    <Cultures>
    </Cultures>
    <LinkerAdditionalOptions>-cultures:en-us%3b</LinkerAdditionalOptions>
    <CompilerAdditionalOptions>
    </CompilerAdditionalOptions>
    <SuppressValidation>True</SuppressValidation>
  </PropertyGroup>
```

---

When I try run this in TFS 2015 I pass SourceLocation via `/p:` arguments:
[image]

If I look at msbuild arguments it evaluated:
[image]

But it failed.

> 2017-01-19T13:39:47.3202914Z     57>D:\agent_work\2\s\Setup\Installation\Installation\Sequences.wxs(11): error LGHT0103: The system cannot find the file '$(Build.BinariesDirectory)MyFile.dll'. [D:\agent_work\2\s\Setup\Installation\Installation\Installation.wixproj]

How to pass my own variables to wixproj in TFS 2015 (vNext) build?

---

**Update:**
Finally I fixed it. As suggested Arkady I just created new `<PropertyGroup>` without conditions and removed `<DefineConstants>` from other places:

```
<Project ToolsVersion="4.0" DefaultTargets="Build" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <Configuration Condition=" '$(Configuration)' == '' ">Debug</Configuration>
    <Platform Condition=" '$(Platform)' == '' ">x86</Platform>
    <ProductVersion>3.8</ProductVersion>
    <ProjectGuid>{63f50ecb-3c8f-448c-ad0d-43739e6ad5f1}</ProjectGuid>
    <SchemaVersion>2.0</SchemaVersion>
    <OutputName>Setup AddIn</OutputName>
    <OutputType>Package</OutputType>
    <WixTargetsPath Condition=" '$(WixTargetsPath)' == '' AND '$(MSBuildExtensionsPath32)' != '' ">$(MSBuildExtensionsPath32)\Microsoft\WiX\v3.x\Wix.targets</WixTargetsPath>
    <WixTargetsPath Condition=" '$(WixTargetsPath)' == '' ">$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\Microsoft\WiX\v3.x\Wix.targets</WixTargetsPath>
    <SccProjectName>SAK</SccProjectName>
    <SccProvider>SAK</SccProvider>
    <SccAuxPath>SAK</SccAuxPath>
    <SccLocalPath>SAK</SccLocalPath>
    <SourceLocation Condition="$(SourceLocation) == '' ">$(SolutionDir)SomeLocation\bin\$(Configuration)\</SourceLocationAddIn>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup>
   <DefineConstants>$(DefineConstants);SourceLocationAddIn=$(SourceLocationAddIn);SourceLocationCA=$(SourceLocationCA)</DefineConstants>
  </PropertyGroup>
   ...
```

It looks `$(DefineConstants);` did the trick. Without this my build doesn't get any parameters.
In addition, I added extra slash at all items in *.wxs file as follows:

```
<File Id="MyFile" Name="MyFile.dll" Source="$(var.SourceLocation)\" Vital="yes"/>
```

Look at `$(var.SourceLocation)\`. 
*(I tried changed this in VS build step but it didn't take any effect)*.
Now I have working solution for development at my PC and CI at build server.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add this without the condition of configuration and platform.

```
 <PropertyGroup>
    <DefineConstants>
      $(DefineConstants);SourceLocation=$(SourceLocation)
    </DefineConstants>
 </PropertyGroup>
```

This way it apply always to all configurations.

Comment: Yes, it does not use any build properties, TFS is running msbuild in the background so it is a common way of passing properties from msbuild to wix.

Comment: I don' quite understand why it should work. My issue that I have to pass argument at buid server to my wix project. my issue that when i pass it, msbuild task does evaluate variable, but my wix proj get name of variable instead of evaluated value.

Comment: You was right. it works. I'm going accept this answer and add some details in my original question. Thank you for pointing me out this!

Comment: Thank you! It's useful solution